# UIBarButtonItem appears in iPad simulator but not in actual app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

I've got a puzzle. I'm a newbie and recently got my first app approved. However, I just noticed that a question mark icon that appears fine when I run the app in Xcode's iPad simulator is invisible for some reason in the actual app store app. The question mark is a UIBarButton item in the toolbar of the starting view controller in the app. The curious thing is the UIBarButton is obviously present in the actual app store app because when I click on that area of the screen, the information screen that it is supposed to show does indeed appear. But for some reason the button itself seems to be invisible in the app store app (but, again, the very same UIBarButton IS visible when I run my program on Xcode's iPad simulator).

One more piece of info: When I first start up the app downloaded from the app store on my iPad, the blue question mark actually does appear briefly in the toolbar of the app for about 1/4 second but then disappears.

Here below is the code segment which is in the viewDidLoad method of the starting view controller. The questionMarkBarButton property is a UIBarButtonItem which brings up an information screen when clicked.

```
    [self.questionMarkBarButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:26.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Any ideas what could be causing this strange behavior? I'm at a loss how to proceed because apparently I can't debug this using Xcode's iPad simulators since they show that the question mark UIBarButtonItem is visible and behaves as expected.

Additonal Info:

Here's how the UIBarButtonItem is declared in the .h file of the view controller:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *questionMarkBarButton;
```

It appears to be hooked up correctly, as evidenced by the fact that the button works (although it is invisible in the app downloaded from the App store).

Also, here is a picture of this part of the storyboard:[image: Storyboard picture]

Finally here is what the starting screen looks like on the Xcode simulator. You can see the question mark button in the toolbar here, but for some reason it is invisible (although present) in the version of the app downloaded from the app store:

[image]

More info:

In examining my app again, I see that there later on in the app I again use a UIBarButtonItem to present an information screen, and it appears and works as it should. The most apparent difference between how I coded these UIBarButtonItems is that for this problematic "question mark" UIBarButtonItem I tried to make the question mark bolder and more prominent by putting the following line of code in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller, whereas I did not use the following line of code with the UIBarButtonItem that appears later in the app (i.e., I let the text in this other UIBarButtonItem just appear in its plain, default form).

```
    [self.questionMarkBarButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:26.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

So unless anyone has any better idea, I guess I'll just submit an update for my app in which I remove this line of code and let the question mark appear in its plain, default style rather then an enlarged, bold style.

**Final edit** (12/7/13)

I removed the code line above and resubmitted my app to the App Store. The app now works properly, with the "?" information button now showing. The bottom line appears to be that the setTitleTextAttributes method does not currently appear to be a good, reliable method to use with UIBarButtonItem objects. It will appear to work fine in the Xcode simulator, and even in testing with your own iPhone and iPods, but for some reason it will not work when people download the app from the Apple store.

Comment: Has this happened to you only or others have experienced the same thing? Try deleting the app from your device and re download it from the App Store again. See if the issue persist after that.

Comment: The app just appeared on the App store so, no, there's no one else to report back to me on this behavior. I downloaded the App store version of my app to two different iPads and they both show this "invisible question mark" behavior. If anyone wants to see the behavior for themselves, the name of my (very first) app is ClueCalculator (Clue board game utility) and the behavior can be seen in the question mark that briefly appears for a fraction of a second in the toolbar and then disappears. Again, this behavior doesn't happen in the Xcode iPad simulator.

Comment: can u explain how you are adding the  UIBarButtonItem on view controller, can give a screenshot of your view design.

Comment: U can try by adding the code in viewDidAppear()...

Comment: Ok I see what you are facing after download. It is an issue with deceleration of uibarbutton item. Can you post the code that declares the bar button?

Comment: OK, I've added the requested info to my original question. See info after "Additional Info:" in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Objective c is case sensitive, Make sure your bar button variable that you create and assign are same . hope this may help you. as this is one of the issue when things go right for simulator instead of device.

Comment: Everything appears to be correct as far as any possible spelling errors or case-sensitivity issues.